# Using jQuery to modify element contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is some my js, jquery snippet:

```
case "username":
  if (inner.length>3 && inner.length < 25)
    input.next().attr("src", "accepted.png");
  else {
    input.next().attr("src", "declined.png");
    input.next("p").innerHTML="დასაშვებია 3-დან 25-მდე სიმბოლო";
  }
  break;
```

and here is my HTML snippet:

```
Username: <input type="text" name="username" onkeypress="First()" class="in">
<img src="" class="vimg">
<p></p>
```

it is updating image src but not adding any text to paragraph, someone can help me?

Comment: Please modify your question title to correctly represent your issue.

Comment: Please show more of the JavaScript code so we can see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
input.next().next()[0].innerHTML="დასაშვებია 3-დან 25-მდე სიმბოლო";
```

Or

```
input.next().next().html("დასაშვებია 3-დან 25-მდე სიმბოლო");
```

Comment: thanks, thanks first method works, and second not... what was wrong?

Comment: See updated version; you do have to use next().next()

Comment: They both should work. Do you get any error? Check the console or can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: can you give me your fb account link? ill add

Comment: Strangely enough I am not on fb. Funny?

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery API docs at http://api.jquery.com/next/, the next selector gets the next *immediate* DOM sibling. Input's next DOM element is the img, not the paragraph.

Adding in the selector "p" tells `.next()` to only give the element when the next immediate element is a paragraph (which it isn't, its still the src tag).

To select the paragraph, you could do `input.next().next()` or you could give the paragraph an id and select it through that by doing `$('#para-id')`.